# List count array by name attribute dynamics information

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, dynamic-arrays, reducers

I need to show an object with the existing attribute list and showing a number of how many times it appears:

Payload:

```
[
    [
        "valor"
    ],
    [
        "tipo de entrada",
        "data entrada",
        "valor"
    ],
    [
        "tipo de entrada",
        "data entrada",
        "valor"
    ],
    [
        "tipo de entrada"
    ],
    [
        "tipo de entrada"
    ],
    [
        "tipo de entrada"
    ],
    [
        "valor"
    ],
    [
        "valor"
    ],
    [
        "valor"
    ],
    [
        "valor"
    ],
    [
        "tipo de entrada",
        "data entrada",
        "valor"
    ]
]
```

Result:

```
{
    valor: 16,
    tipo_entrada: 9,
    dqta_entrada: 6
}
```

being that list of attributes dynamically, it can contain other values ​​(value, name, age ...)

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten your array using `array#flat()` and then using `array#reduce` count the frequency of each word.

```js
const arr = [ [ "valor" ], [ "tipo de entrada", "data entrada", "valor" ], [ "tipo de entrada", "data entrada", "valor" ], [ "tipo de entrada" ], [ "tipo de entrada" ], [ "tipo de entrada" ], [ "valor" ], [ "valor" ], [ "valor" ], [ "valor" ], [ "tipo de entrada", "data entrada", "valor" ] ],
      result = arr.flat().reduce((r, word) => {
        r[word] = (r[word] ?? 0) + 1;
        return r;
      },{});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner :

```js
var mainData = [ [ "valor" ], [ "tipo de entrada", "data entrada", "valor" ], [ "tipo de entrada", "data entrada", "valor" ], [ "tipo de entrada" ], [ "tipo de entrada" ], [ "tipo de entrada" ], [ "valor" ], [ "valor" ], [ "valor" ], [ "valor" ], [ "tipo de entrada", "data entrada", "valor" ] ]

var resultObj = {};
mainData.map(data => data.forEach(subData => { resultObj[subData] = (Object.keys(resultObj).indexOf(subData) == -1 ? 1 : resultObj[subData] + 1) }))
console.log(resultObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and play around with it.

This code defines and explain a way of resolving your problem:

```js
const result = {};
const initialArray = [['tomato'], ['ketchup', 'potato']];
const strings = initialArray.flat(); // ['tomato', 'ketchup', 'potato']

for (const string of strings) {
  // string is 'tomato' for example
  // result[string] would then be result[tomato]

  if (result[string]) {
    result[string] += 1; // result.tomato already exists? Add 1 to it
  } else {
    result[string] = 1; // if it does not exists, create it with value 1
  }
}
```